# Reference a column of a record, from a variable holding the column name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

In a function in *plpgsql* language and having:

1. `"col" CHARACTER VARYING = 'a';` (can be `'b'`)
2. `"rec" RECORD;` Holding records from: `(SELECT 1 AS "a", 2 AS "b")`
3. `"res" INTEGER;`

I need to reference the named column in `"col"`, from `"rec"`. So if `"col"` has `'b'` I will reference `"rec"."b"`, and then save its value into `"res"`.

Comment: As *always*, version of PostgreSQL in use?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter not specified, so assume latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reference the columns of an *anonymous record* type by name in plpgsql. Even though you spell out column aliases in your example in the `SELECT` statement, those are just noise and discarded.

If you want to reference elements of a record type by name, you need to use a well-known type. Either create and use a type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_composite_type(a int, b int);
```

Or use the row type associated with any existing table. You can just write the table name as data type.

```
DECLARE
   rec my_composite_type;
...
```

Then you need a *conditional statement* or *dynamic SQL* to use the *value* of `"col"` as identifier.

Conditional statement:

```
IF col = 'a' THEN
   res := rec.a;
ELSIF col = 'b' THEN
   res := rec.b;
ELSE
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected value in variable "col": %', col;
END IF;
```

For just two possible cases, that's the way to go.
Or dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.' || col
INTO res
USING rec;
```

I don't see a problem here, but be wary of SQL injection with dynamic SQL. If `col` can hold arbitrary data, you need to escape it with [`quote_ident()` or `format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html)

#### Demo

Demonstrating the more powerful, but also trickier variant with dynamic SQL.

Quick & dirty way to create a (temporary!) known type for testing:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE rec_ab(a int, b int);
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test()
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
DECLARE
    col   text := 'a';  -- can be 'b'
    rec   rec_ab;
    res   int;
BEGIN
    rec := '(1, 2)'::rec_ab;

    EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.' || col
    INTO res
    USING rec;

    RETURN res;
END
$func$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_test();
```

Returns:

```
f_test
----
1
```